# How can I call an Directive inside ngRepeat?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

When I tried to call an Directive inside ngRepeat is failing.
But if call the same directive outside ngRepeat is working fine.

Please check the below code:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src ="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body ng-app = "myApp">
      <div ng-controller = "myCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="list in lists">
          <div>{{fileName}}</div>
           <input type = "file" id=list file-model = "myFile"/>
           <button ng-click = "uploadFile()">upload me</button>
        </div> 
      </div>

  <script>
     var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

     myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
        return {

           restrict: 'E',
           link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
              var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
              var modelSetter = model.assign;

              element.bind('change', function(){
                 $scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter($scope, element[0].files[0]);
                 });
              });
           }
        };
     }]);

     myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
       $scope.lists=[1,2,3];
        $scope.uploadFile = function(){
           var file = $scope.myFile;

           console.log('file is ' );
           console.dir(file);
           $scope.fileName=file.name;

        /*   var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload";
           fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);*/
        };
     }]);

  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

How to invoke the directive from ng-repeat?

Comment: You are restricting your directive to 'E'- element and using it as attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You are restricting your directive to 'E'- element and using it as attribute. Change restrict property to EA.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

     myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
        return {

           restrict: 'EA',
           link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
              var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
              var modelSetter = model.assign;

              element.bind('change', function(){
                 $scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter($scope, element[0].files[0]);
                 });
              });
           }
        };
     }]);
```